# Drawing arrows using tikz package (fine tuning coordinates)

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I am making some lecture slides for my class and sometimes I need to label the different components of the C/C++ program. For this I have referred to the post [How can I draw arrows within a listing to explain positional association?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204417/how-can-i-draw-arrows-within-a-listing-to-explain-positional-association) but still can't make it out.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

%% This is to put the lstlisting in the center but horizontally
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{CenteredBox}{% 
\begin{Sbox}}{% Save the content in a box
\end{Sbox}\centerline{\parbox{\wd\@Sbox}{\TheSbox}}}% And output it centered
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
 \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[text=black,
       inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}

\newcommand{\VerticalShiftForArrows}{0.0em,+2.75ex}%
\newcommand{\VerticalShiftForBar}{0.0em,+2.0ex}%
\newcommand{\Stub}{0.0em,-0.6ex}%
\newcommand{\DrawOverBar}[3][]{%
    \coordinate (top left)  at ($(#2)       +(\VerticalShiftForBar)$);
    \coordinate (start)     at ($(top left) +(\Stub)$);
    \coordinate (top right) at ($(#3)       +(\VerticalShiftForBar)$);
    \coordinate (end)       at ($(top right)+(\Stub)$);
    \draw [#1] (start) -- (top left) -- (top right) -- (end);
}%
\newcommand{\DrawArrows}[3][]{%
\coordinate (Start Mid) at ($(#2Left)!0.5!(#2Right) + (\VerticalShiftForArrows)$);
\coordinate (End Mid)   at ($(#3Left)!0.5!(#3Right) + (\VerticalShiftForArrows)$);

\draw[-stealth, thick, #1] (Start Mid) to (End Mid);
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Functions}
\lstset{language=C,
basicstyle=\fontsize{11pt}{9.2}\selectfont\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
morecomment=[l][\color{magenta}]{\#},
emph={raise_to_power},emphstyle=\textbf
}
\begin{itemize}
\item \tikzmark{bLeft}{}Function name\tikzmark{bRight}{}
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}[thp]
\begin{CenteredBox}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},basicstyle=\ttfamily]
int (*@\tikzmark{aLeft}{}@*)raise_to_power(*@\tikzmark{aRight}{}@*) (int base, int exponent)
{
int result = 1;
for (i=0; i<exponent; i=i+1)
{
  result = result * base;
}
return result;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{CenteredBox}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\renewcommand{\VerticalShiftForBar}{0.0em,-0.8ex}%
\renewcommand{\Stub}{0.0em,+0.6ex}%
\DrawOverBar[-, red, thick]{aLeft.south}{aRight.south}
\renewcommand{\VerticalShiftForArrows}{0.0em,0ex}
\DrawArrows[red,in=20,out=160]{b}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

As can be seen the arrow do start and end at the proper midpoints but looks a little ugly. How can I fine tune the coordinates. Please suggest if there is any other good solution.

Comment: You mean something like `\DrawArrows[red,in=-140,out=-20]{[yshift=-1mm]b}{[yshift=-3mm]a}` ?

Comment: @percusse Exactly. This is what I needed. Is there any other solution for this kind of problem which is more elegant. I see that with this approach, there is a lot to be done with angle tweaking too.

Comment: In terms of elegance, I don't know much because it is tough to code beauty. I would do all by hand actually since I generally tweak them in the last version anyhow. But I might be overzealous over the details.

Comment: You can use `bend left` instead of `in` and `out`.

Comment: @percusse Would you like to write up an answer?

Comment: My proposal is to use the overlay functions in beamer class and let a box appear, which contains "Function Name" instead of drawing an arrow to the headline.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments