# Problem with listings and Tikz

Tags: beamer, listings, tikz-arrows

I have a problem when I try to combine listings, tikz and beamer packages.

What I want : 
1. be able to put some "mark points in my source code";
2. be able to draw an arrow between them;

I tried to do this : [How can I draw arrows within a listing to explain positional association?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204417/how-can-i-draw-arrows-within-a-listing-to-explain-positional-association) but it doesn't  work for me :'(

here's my minimum source code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings} %http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf
\lstset{language=C++}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204417/how-can-i-draw-arrows-within-a-listing-to-explain-positional-association
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
   \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[text=black,
       inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[fragile]{}
 \begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}]
   for([e1]; [e2]; [e3])
   {
     instruction(s);
     if (condition) break;(*@\tikzmark{aBeg}{}@*)
     instruction(s);(*@\tikzmark{aEnd}{}@*)
   }
   (*@
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \node (Start) at (aBeg.{east}) {};
     \node  (Ending) at (aEnd.{north west}) {};
     %\draw Start -- Ending;
      \end{tikzpicture}
    *@) 
 \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. `*@)` is not what you defined as closing character
2. missing `()` around the nodes.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings} %http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf
\lstset{language=C++}

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204417/how-can-i-draw-arrows-within-a-listing-to-explain-positional-association
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
   \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[text=black,
       inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[fragile]{}
 \begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}]
   for([e1]; [e2]; [e3])
   {
     instruction(s);
     if (condition) break;(*@\tikzmark{aBeg}{}@*)
     instruction(s);(*@\tikzmark{aEnd}{}@*)
   }
   (*@
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
     \node (Start) at (aBeg.{east}) {};
     \node  (Ending) at (aEnd.{north west}) {};
     \draw[->] (Start) -- (Ending);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    @*) 
 \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]