# How to draw a graph for source code?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I have to draw a graph like the following or similar:

[image]

I have already explored tikz and forest package and have not came anything like this.
Can anyone please provide me any pointer or package name about how to draw a graph like this.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204417/47927 . Also, please show some code of yours, at least something we can work with.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thanks - but it does not have nice coloring and different kind of edges.

Comment: I would suggest you first take a look into the `listings` (which allows for code highlighting) and the `tikzmark` packages and how to combine both. Coloring the edges or making them dotted or arrows is then probably only a minor task.

Comment: @JasperHabicht are there any visual editor app for tikzmark that you are aware off.

Comment: @Exploring Probably not, you don't have something like a visual editor app for `tikzmark` unfortunately.

Comment: I suggest you edit this question once you got some first code and ask for reopening in case you need more help with this. It may be a bit fiddly in the end to get the arrows right.